# Как в vqmod-e поменять файл?

Tags: opencart

В одном файле я должен поменять сразу в двух местах. Как это реализовать в vqmod и ocmod-e ?

```
   <file name="system/library/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p.status = '1'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $multiproduct_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_multistore multi WHERE multi.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND multi.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ");
            //MULTISTORE
            if ($multiproduct_query->num_rows) {
                $product_query->row['price'] = $multiproduct_query->row['price'];
                $product_query->row['quantity'] = $multiproduct_query->row['quantity'];
            }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $product_special_query = $this->db->query("SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
        // Product Specials
                $product_special_query = $this->db->query("SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");

                if ($product_special_query->num_rows) {
                    $price = $product_special_query->row['price'];
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

Делаю так не получается

Comment: Расширьте ваш пример. так-то он похож на vqMod, но не видно начало. Может там, в начале, вы не правильно декларируете.

Comment: Посмотрев сегодня увидел что данный запрос работает) Проблемы походу были связаны с кэшированием. Прошу прощения за без полезные вопросы